# How to prevent interactive ssh login?

Tags: linux, git, permissions, ssh

Short Question:
How do i prevent interactive(human) ssh login on a Linux machine?

The unix accounts should be available only for non-interactive ssh use (like via some other program), for eg: via a GIT client etc...

The idea is to prevent end-users from logging into the Linux machine interactively. It is strictly meant to be used via a GIT client program to checkin-checkout files.

Answer (score 1):

Change the user's default shell to [`git-shell`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shell.html).

```
chsh -s `which git-shell` <USER>
```

Comment: How can i change back to the original default shell?

Comment: `chsh -s /bin/bash <USER>`, assuming bash was your default shell.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

See how [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) organize the access to any git command through a [forced-command script](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858) in ssh, mentioned in `authorized_keys`.

The [Gitolite script `gl-auth-command`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/src/gl-auth-command) explicitly prevents any interactive session, while allowing git commands.